# How to change port 80 and avoid end url with port number

Tags: apache, port

I have changed my port 80 long time ago to 90. But i need to end url with port number and its getting annoying. So my question is if there is any way to avoid that?

Comment: The only way to avoid port numbers is to use the standard port numbers for the protocol involved (80 and 443 for HTTPS).

Comment: If you cannot get your application hosted on port 80, you could maybe get a reverse proxy installed there.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. The reason why i had to change port 80 was because after installing Windows 10 some application named "System" was using port 80. And i think its more safe to change the port in xampp than changing the port for that system application or whatever it is.